# bash convert epoch time in tail of csv to human readable

Tags: awk, printf, epoch, tail

I've spent a few hours trawling over dozens of StackOverflow questions, and they have gotten me closer to my answer, but not quite all the way.

I'm trying to combine several bash commands into one; to tail a csv log file, and convert the epoch dtstamp to human readable on the fly. So far I have worked through the following steps:

#1. Get just the columns I want from the log file:

```
tail -F config.log |awk -F, '{printf $1}{printf $3}{printf $4}{printf "   "}{print    $5}'
AW.BS._74.OD              3.000   0001630507243.820532   Local User
AW.BS._74.OnAction        3       0001630507243.820532   Local User
AW.BS._75.OfD             3.000   0001630507243.821193   Local User
AW.BS._75.OD              3.000   0001630507243.821193   Local User
AW.BS._75.OA              3       0001630507243.821193   Local User
AW.BS._76.OfD             3.000   0001630507243.821857   Local User
AW.BS._76.OD              3.000   0001630507243.821857   Local User
AW.BS._76.OA              3       0001630507243.821857   Local User
T.C._5.T.A._2.I                   0001630511595.829306   Local User
T.C._5.T.A._2.I                   0001630540127.214874   Local User
```

#2. Extract epoch on it's own

```
tail -F config.log |awk -F, '{print $4}'
0001630507243.820532
0001630507243.820532
0001630507243.821193
0001630507243.821193
0001630507243.821193
0001630507243.821857
0001630507243.821857
0001630507243.821857
0001630511595.829306
0001630540127.214874
```

#3. date doesn't like leading zeros or trailing decimals on an epoch time it's converting, so remove them:

```
tail config.log |awk -F, '{print $4}' |sed 's/^0*//' |sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//'

1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630507243
1630511595
```

However - this step doesn't work if I'm using -F with tail. :(

#4 Test date conversion: works fine with a static epoch time:

```
date -d @1630540127
Wed Sep  1 23:48:47 GMT 2021
```

So, I can do each part on it's own, but I can't manage to combine them to see a live update of the log file showing columns 1, 3, <4 converted to readable> 5.

What have I missed?

Thanks for your help Gurus.

Comment: Never do `printf $1`, always do `printf "%s", $1` instead as the former will fail when the input contains printf formatting strings such as `%s`. That applies to using printf with any input data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this GNU `awk`

```
$ TZ=GMT awk '{ s=strftime("%a %b %d %T %Z %Y",$(NF-2));print $0,s }' scott.txt
AW.BS._74.OD              3.000   0001630507243.820532   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._74.OnAction        3       0001630507243.820532   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._75.OfD             3.000   0001630507243.821193   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._75.OD              3.000   0001630507243.821193   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._75.OA              3       0001630507243.821193   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._76.OfD             3.000   0001630507243.821857   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._76.OD              3.000   0001630507243.821857   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
AW.BS._76.OA              3       0001630507243.821857   Local User Wed Sep 01 14:40:43 GMT 2021
T.C._5.T.A._2.I                   0001630511595.829306   Local User Wed Sep 01 15:53:15 GMT 2021
T.C._5.T.A._2.I                   0001630540127.214874   Local User Wed Sep 01 23:48:47 GMT 2021
```

Comment: Thanks @stack0114106, unfortunately my Linux build (compact for an embedded device, I can't add to it) doesn't know what strftime is. :(

Comment: @Scott what does `awk --version` output? Linux usually comes with GNU awk, it'd be odd for you to have GNU date and GNU tail (as your question tells us you do by the options you're using for them) but not have GNU awk, and `strftime()` has been part of GNU awk for 11 years so it'd be odd if you have a version of gawk without it.

Comment: @EdMorton: 
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ awk --version
awk: unrecognized option '--version'
BusyBox v1.17.1 (2021-04-05 12:13:07 IST) multi-call binary.

Usage: awk [OPTIONS] [AWK_PROGRAM] [FILE]...

Options:
        -v VAR=VAL      Set variable
        -F SEP          Use SEP as field separator
        -f FILE         Read program from FILE

[user@Dreadnaught /bin]$ l |grep awk
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Apr  5 07:20 awk -> busybox

It's BusyBox, an embedded Linux for low power controllers.

Comment: Looks like you're using BusyBox awk instead of GNU awk. It may already be on your system but not the first one in your PATH so take a look for it and if it's not present then install it as it has a ton of useful functionality over BusyBox awk.

Comment: I can't install programs unfortunately, the controller OS is built and fixed. I can modify all the config files, but I can't install new programs.

Comment: if you can't find/install GNU awk then you should probably accept this answer anyway and ask a new followup question (but this time make sure to state your awk version in it) as it's unlikely anyone's still looking at this question after all this time has passed.